# Devise token auth preventing migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

My rails app is using Devise. I added devise_token_auth so I can link the app to an android app.

*In the routes*

```
namespace :api do
scope :v1 do
  #mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
end
end
```

*in the initializer*

```
# enable_standard_devise_support = false #for working with Devise
```

(in addition the other code that was in the file)

I got this error

```
:~/workspace (master) $ rake db:migrate
-- [](4.2)
-- [](4.2)
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x00000002c3c470>
```

Solution, I deleted modified the migration file

```
class DeviseTokenAuthCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
```

to

```
class DeviseTokenAuthCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
```

I stopped getting the error but now I got this

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" IN ........
```

Please help, how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps :

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```